# How to get redirected to a particular step in a wizard in vue and typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, web, quasar

The wizard has 6 steps in which the last step has a redirecting button other than finish button.The user when clicks the redirect button it should take the user back to step 4 of the wizard and the user has to perform steps 5 and 6 to complete the wizard.

**step6.ts**

```
<router-link
        to="/stepFour"
        custom
        v-slot="{ navigate }"
>
        <q-btn
          :ripple="false"
          flat
          :label="$t('pages.projects.project.deviceConnection.validation.symbolDidntBlink')"
          @click="navigate"
          role="link"
        />
</router-link>
```

**router.ts**

```
  const routes = [
  //connect: redirect
  {
    path: 'stepFour',
    name: 'step4',
    component: () => import('components/connection/4_stepFour/stepFour.vue'),
    props: {
      slaveLevel: 1,
    },
  },
];
```

**wizard.vue**

```
<template>
  <q-stepper
    v-bind:value="value"
    v-on:input="handleInput"
    ref="stepper"
    color="primary"
    flat
    class="c-stepper"
    @transition="transitionPanel"
  >
    <slot />

    <template v-slot:navigation>
      <q-card-actions class="c-wizarDialog__footer c-btn__action" align="center">
        <q-btn
          v-if="value > 1 && !disablePreviousButton"
          :ripple="false"
          :disable="disablePreviousButton"
          icon="chevron_left"
          flat
          dense
          size="lg"
          text-color="primary"
          @click="goPrevious($refs)"
          data-cy="wizard-back"
          class="c-btn--previous"
        />

        <q-btn
          :ripple="false"
          v-if="value === numberOfSteps"
          :disable="disableFinishButtonState"
          @click="finish(actionButtonFunction)"
          color="primary"
          :label="$t('general.finish')"
          class="c-btn--finish full-width"
          data-cy="wizard-finish"
        />

        <q-btn
          v-else-if="pShowNextButton"
          :ripple="false"
          :disabled="disableNextButton"
          @click="goToNextStep($refs)"
          color="primary"
          class="c-btn--continue full-width"
          data-cy="wizard-continue"
        >
          {{ $t('general.continue') }}
        </q-btn>
      </q-card-actions>
    </template>
  </q-stepper>
</template>
```

**connection.ts**

```
<template>
  <WizardDialog
    :title="$t('components.appBar.connection')"
    :actionButtonTitle="$t('general.createButtonText')"
    v-on:dialogVisibility="handleDialogVisibility"
    :cancelButtonLabel="''"
  >
    <Wizard
      :number-of-steps="numberOfSteps"
      v-model="step"
      :action-button-function="finishFunction"
      :disable-next-button="disableNextButton"
      :has-step-errors="hasStepErrors"
    >
      <WizardStep
        class="c-identifyDialog"
        :number-of-steps="numberOfSteps"
        :name="0"
        :done="step > 0"
      >
//wizard steps from 1 to 5

      <WizardStep :number-of-steps="numberOfSteps" :name="6" :done="step > 6" v-if="!isHelp">
        <StepSix />
      </WizardStep>
    </Wizard>
  </WizardDialog>
</template>
```

the code written redirects the user to step 4 but it is not inside the wizard rather it is displayed for the whole page. Could someone help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Router-links are specifically meant to change your app's current page, which is why you see your stepFour component completely replace everything.  Review Quasar's [QStepper API documentation](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/stepper#api--qstepper).  There is no need to use router-links to control navigation of the component. It's built into the component with `v-model`, where changing the v-model value will change which step the component displays.  A very basic example:

```html
<q-stepper
  v-model="step"
>
  <q-step :name="1" />
  <q-step :name="2" />
  <q-step :name="3" />
</q-stepper>
```

Now in a function if you set `step` to a value 1, 2 or 3, q-stepper will set the current displayed step to that same named q-step child component.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the  in the step6.ts. Change the wizard.ts as follows.

```
  <WizardStep :number-of-steps="numberOfSteps" :name="6" :done="step > 6" v-if="!isHelp">
    <StepSix ref="step6" />
    <div >
    <q-btn
        :ripple="false"
        flat
        color="primary"
        class="q-mb-sm full-width"
        @click="redirect()"
      >
        {{ $t('pages.projects.project.deviceConnection.validation.symbolDidntBlink') }}
      </q-btn>
    </div>
  </WizardStep>
```

This redirects the user to step4 inside the wizard.